# How to schedule a script which executes daily? [OSX]

Tags: macos, unix, cron, osx-yosemite, launchd

I have a python script which I want to run daily at let's say 9 am. But if the system is not on at that time, the script should run as soon as the computer gets turned on again.

I'm looking for something like `anacron`.

How can I achieve this? Cron job doesn't fulfill my purpose.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 'the script runs as soon as it boots.'

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question, since I, for one, am not sure what you're asking.  As it reads right now it appears that you want the script to run even when the machine is turned off, which is clearly impossible.

Comment: @NormanGray Sorry about that. I've edited the question. Basically I want if the system is not on at the time of execution of job it runs script as soon as the computer gets turned on back again.

Answer (score 4):

Create a [Launch Daemon](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) file, set its ownership to root:wheel and permissions to 644, and place it in /Library/LaunchDaemons. At minimum, the file should contain something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.maintenance</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/path/to/your/script</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>9</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Note that although a missed run of the daemon will be made up at the next opportunity, it'll "coalesce" multiple missed runs. For example, if the computer is off for 5 days, the daemon will be run just once when it finally starts up.

Answer (score 1):

Gordon's answer is right; launchd will get the job done.

A few tips that may help:

- Be aware of the difference between Launch Daemons (they run at boot) and Launch Agents (they run on login). Basically, do you want your script to run only if you are already logged in? This post is helpful: http://www.grivet-tools.com/blog/2014/launchdaemons-vs-launchagents/
- Use LaunchControl http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/. It's a GUI that helps you manage your jobs and simplifies dealing with plists. With it, just create a new User Agent (or Global Daemon), specify the time of day with "StartCalendarInterval" and it will work. If it doesn't, LaunchControl will help you debug too (by helping you pipe to standard error and standard out).

Comment: 1st link now redirects to shady IP-addressed site. Here's the most recentish WBM snapshot of it: https://web.archive.org/web/20191108181216/http://www.grivet-tools.com/blog/2014/launchdaemons-vs-launchagents/